# Parametric segmented or piecewise regression with heteroscedastic errors

Tags: heteroscedasticity, panel-data, piecewise-linear

I am fitting longitudinal data with an increase in variance over time. The standard physiological model is a bi- or tri-linear model with variable breakpoints. The estimated parameters are used to describe rate of growth and time to maturity. 
Is there an efficient method to account for within-segment heteroscedastic errors in a parametric piecewise regression model?